# How to access src/dist folder in Gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle

I'm developing Java application on Eclipse, using Gradle.  From the application I want to access the files in `src/dist` folder.  When developing, I can access the files by using the path `src/dist`.  But when the application was exported to "distributed" style (by using Gradle task `installDist`), the relative path from `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to the files in `src/dist` will change.

What it the best way to access to those files seamlessly both while developing and after distributed, either by changing my Java source code or Gradle build script?  I have come up with following ideas:

- Add an option that indicates the actual location of the files.  When running on Eclipse I can add the options to the Run Configuration.
- Check if the program is running inside jar.  I can do it by checking `getResources()` or something.

Please tell me if you have better way to achieve this, or what is the best practice from the viewpoint of maintainability.

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: Wouldn't loading resources from your classpath, which basically is the dist directory, be an option?

Comment: @Antoniossss I want to access from the program to the files to get the data of questions list (I'm making a quiz game).

Comment: @ErikPragt How can I do that?

Comment: You should use resources for that

Comment: What if I want to change it afterward?